TextMate syntax highlighting logic in python
I'm trying to parse the textmate schema in python and use it for syntax highlighting I think I'm currently done with the parsing due to the output being pretty on point.
What I'm stuck at currently is implementing the logic of the syntax highlighting. What should be highlighted or not, and how can I avoid overlapping. so for example string.quoted.single.python doesn't get overlapped by meta.function-call.python.
I'm not really sure what rules does vscode use. Maybe someone has any idea?
with open("MagicPython.tmLanguage.json", "r") as fin:
    import json

    grammar = TextMateGrammar(json.load(fin))
    line = "print('True') # Test"
    result = grammar.parse(line)
    
    print(line, ":")
    print()
    for scope, (start, end) in result:
        print("Token: ", line[start:end])
        print("Scope:", scope)
        print("Start,End:", f"({start},{end})")
        print("")
with open("MagicPython.tmLanguage.json", "r") as fin:
    import json

    grammar = TextMateGrammar(json.load(fin))
    line = "print('True') # Test"
    result = grammar.parse(line)
    
    print(line, ":")
    print()
    for scope, (start, end) in result:
        print("Token: ", line[start:end])
        print("Scope:", scope)
        print("Start,End:", f"({start},{end})")
        print("")
print('True') # Test :

Token:  #
Scope: punctuation.definition.comment.python
Start,End: (14,15)

Token:  # Test
Scope: comment.line.number-sign.python
Start,End: (14,20)

Token:  True
Scope: constant.language.python
Start,End: (7,11)

Token:  
Scope: invalid.illegal.prefix.python
Start,End: (19,19)

Token:  
Scope: storage.type.string.python
Start,End: (19,19)

Token:  '
Scope: punctuation.definition.string.begin.python
Start,End: (6,7)

Token:  '
Scope: punctuation.definition.string.end.python
Start,End: (11,12)

Token:  
Scope: invalid.illegal.newline.python
Start,End: (19,19)

Token:  'True'
Scope: string.quoted.single.python
Start,End: (6,12)

Token:  (
Scope: punctuation.parenthesis.begin.python
Start,End: (5,6)

Token:  )
Scope: punctuation.parenthesis.end.python
Start,End: (12,13)

Token:  True
Scope: constant.language.python
Start,End: (7,11)

Token:  
Scope: invalid.illegal.prefix.python
Start,End: (11,11)

Token:  
Scope: storage.type.string.python
Start,End: (11,11)

Token:  '
Scope: punctuation.definition.string.begin.python
Start,End: (6,7)

Token:  '
Scope: punctuation.definition.string.end.python
Start,End: (11,12)

Token:  
Scope: invalid.illegal.newline.python
Start,End: (11,11)

Token:  'True'
Scope: string.quoted.single.python
Start,End: (6,12)

Token:  )
Scope: punctuation.definition.arguments.end.python
Start,End: (12,13)

Token:  print('True')
Scope: meta.function-call.python
Start,End: (0,13)

Token:  True
Scope: keyword.illegal.name.python
Start,End: (7,11)

Token:  print
Scope: support.function.builtin.python
Start,End: (0,5)

Token:  print
Scope: meta.function-call.generic.python
Start,End: (0,5)

Token:  print
Scope: support.function.builtin.python
Start,End: (0,5)

I tried highlighting each rule one by one, and I ended up with a rainbow
